# Custom error templates in test environment

Tags: symfony, twig

I have overriden default error templates by creating my own one at `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.twig`

It works fine on `prod` environment, as expected.

My functional tests are running with `debug` disabled, following [Kris Wallsmith's instructions](http://kriswallsmith.net/post/27979797907/get-fast-an-easy-symfony2-phpunit-optimization).

When a test drives to an error, the default `TwigBundle` error template is returned instead of the custom one.

Summarizing:

- Template overrides work for `prod`
- Disabling debug works for `test`
- **Template overrides do not work for `test`**

Any clue on how to get these template overrides on test environment?

Comment: When I get weird problems with templates in different environments, I tend to run `php app/console cache:clear --env=test or stag or prod` which always solves the problems. Since you haven't mentined, have you tried cache clear? I did very similar thing to yours and didn't actually have any problems.

Comment: Yes, I have tried cleaning cache, rebuilding the bootstrap file and all that kind of tasks. Nothing worked. It's a quite complex application, I'm afraid that something is interacting with the error handler silently.

Comment: @albertedevigo did you find a solution for that? I'm interested in checking that a text appears in the `error404.html.twig`. On the screen I can load it, but when I get the path `_error/404` from the functional tests, it returns the complete exception page. SF ver is `v5.3.6`.